# CRF model could be loaded as NER Annotator?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have made my own CRF model. Now I want to do testing of that model, I need to load that model. A [demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kfv309bbcqd1o9/NERDemo.java?dl=0) is given in documentation. But my question is can I use this model with **NER annotator** of Stanford Corenlp? Can I do following things.

```
Properties          props;
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse,ner");
props.put("ner.model", "myCrf-model.ser.gz");
```

I need to know **pros and cons** of using these lines of code instead of those which are given in [demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kfv309bbcqd1o9/NERDemo.java?dl=0). What would be effect in results?

I will be thankful to you if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just supply the models you trained to the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline and you will get the same results.

Comment: Thank for your response. One more thing if I go with this technique and Let say model which I have made, its training data have POS and LEMMA of each token and I am using them through austen.prop. Now when I will use above technique (CRF model through NER annotator) should I need to worry about POS and LEMMA at testing time OR StanfordCoreNLP will handle this? I need to know POS and LEMMA features are using at testing time through above lines of code? OR I have to do something else?